# Get number of employee group by division or department from BambooHR using Powershell

Tags: powershell, api, group-by, get, rate

So it is my fist time working with BambooHR and I have basic knowledge on using Powershell.

I have task the required me to calculate the retention rate of the staff from each division on the company.

I want first to get number of employees per each division.

I have tried this:

```
$headers=@{}
$headers.Add("accept", "application/json")
$headers.Add("authorization", "Basic api")
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/company/v1/employees/150/?fields=division' -Method GET -Headers $headers
$response
```

Result:

```
Content       : {"id":"150","division":"######"}
```

However it retrieve only one one employee even if I remove the id from the url. And it's not what I am looking for, and I don't have idea on how to write it. It should return the number of employees in each division.

Comment: So, where's the code you're having trouble with?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us what you have tried yourself. Note this is *not* a script factory. You will need to write the script yourself. If you run into a problem that isn't yet covered by the existing questions and answers, you might post your [mcve] here so that we might be able to help you further. See also: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Actually I don't have idea how to start the code but I updated my question with what I have tried so far.

Comment: No experience with BambooHR, but looking at their examples, you may want to add `&onlyCurrent=false` to the url